# Using RichTextBox SelectionTabs property in winforms

Tags: winforms, richtextbox

In a winforms application, I'm using a RichTextBox and I'm trying to reduce the output from a '\t' to 4 spaces from whatever the default is.
I have this in the form's OnLoad

```
 _richTextBox.Text = "1\t2\t3\t4\t5";
 _richTextBox.SelectAll();
 _richTextBox.SelectionTabs = new int[]  {100,200,300,400 };
```

I have a breakpoint before and after this snippet. The SelectionTabs is set to  {int[0]} (empty int array) before and after the assignment. Can anyone tell me why my assignment is not going through?

Comment: quite difficult to understand your problem, can you add more details

Comment: No repro, this code works fine when I try it.  Both on screen and in the debugger.  There's no obvious failure mode, nor have I ever seen one reported.

Comment: There were  some event handlers on the RichTextBox (GotFocus, TextChanged, SwelectionChanged, etc). I disabled all of them and it started working. Now I'm trying to figure out what exactly those eventhandlers were doing that was preventing the setting of SelectionTabs.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the `SelectionTabs` property **before** putting anything into the text box (and/or selecting anything).

See [Modifying default tab size in RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154204/modifying-default-tab-size-in-richtextbox).