# UITextView line height

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

Not sure if that was mentioned before, but I could not find the answer anywhere.

I have `UITextView` with bunch of text (about 130 lines) varies, I need to get height of 5 lines of that text in my `UITextView`

Comment: I didn't get what is your issue, do you need to set multiple line heights? or one for the 5 lines?

Comment: hopefully my updated question helps @piyuj

Comment: You may be able to translate the height of one line given its font size.  See 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776767/what-exactly-is-uifonts-point-size

Comment: Use `textView.firstRectForRange` passing in your range of text. This will return a CGRect and you can get the height from that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
textView.font.lineHeight * 5
```

Comment: Haha, cant believe it is that simple, this is exactly what I needed

Comment: I would add self.font!.lineHeight*5+textView.textContainerInset.top to add top margin