# Are font sizes in Photoshop the same as in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts

an iPhone app that I've designed is being developed overseas. The app is a note- taking application.

The font size of the screen when typing a new note is Helvetica Neue, Regular 34px (the same as the equivalent screen in the native Apple Notes app).

However the programmer insist this is far too big and that the current size (14) is the correct size, even though in the test builds it is just far too small.

My question is this- do font sizes in photoshop translate into the font size values in Xcode? As I am confused as to why this is such an issue. I expect he is somehow not coding it correctly or making an error in judgement.

Answer (score 1):

This post explains font point sizes: [Font size in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059101/font-size-in-pixels)

In short: No, it isn't the same.

Comment: but font sizes in photoshop are based on points (pt), as are iPhone apps. I have made the designs in photoshop with the exact art board size as the iPhone resolution and DPI so i do not see why there should be any difference?

Comment: Then keep in mind that in iOS devices with retina display, 1 point = 2 pixels.

Comment: Also, he can (and should) send you at least a screenshot with different fonts and sizes so you can see how it really looks.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So a font size in photoshop of 32pt would equate to half that size on retina displays (16)? And yes I agree, I will request a screenshot if he still can't get the sizes to match.