# UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16.0) = font size ... ?? px in HTML

Tags: ios, swift, uifont

I have UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16.0)
I want to know the font size pixels on  html

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059101/font-size-in-pixels

Comment: Excuse me, help me to calculate it.

Answer (score 0):

As @CynicismRising [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059101/font-size-in-pixels):- Point sizes are defined as 1/72 of an inch. That is, a 72-point font is approximately 1 inch from the lowest descent to the highest ascent. So the maximum height of a glyph in a 72pt font is about 1 inch.

Comment: Sorry, I could question unclear.
I want to convert font size from  UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16.0)  to text size scoop on HTML(it px).

Comment: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16.0) = font size ... ?? px  in HTML