# Can I Set an Image to *Not* Auto-Resize?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, closedxml

I have a "template" Excel file with a few basic things set for a layout (some merged cells, some column widths, etc.), which is then used by ClosedXML to populate with data.  At a basic level it's as simple as:

```
var workbook = new XLWorkbook(filePath);
workbook.Worksheets.Single().Cell(1, 4).Value = someTextValue;
workbook.Worksheets.Single().Cell(1, 4).Style.Alignment.WrapText = true;
// set other values, etc.
```

The overall process involves copying the file to another stream, returning it for download from a web app, that sort of thing.

One of the cells in the static template file has an image.  Another cell on that row needs to auto-expand to fit wrapping text with carriage returns.  The auto-expansion of the row works fine when setting the `WrapText` property above.  However, the *image* is also expanding its height.  (Thus becoming significantly distorted.)

In the file itself I've right-clicked on the image to set its format, and under "Size & Properties" I've explicitly selected "Don't move or size with cells".  However, the auto-resizing of the row taking place via the ClosedXML interaction is still causing the image to resize.

Another thing I've tried is to somehow "separate" the image from the row by putting it inside of a text box.  However it would appear that both the image and the text box equally "float" above the cells and the image can't be placed inside of the text box (or I don't know how).

It appears that ClosedXML doesn't have much support for images (unless I'm just not seeing it).  Is there perhaps any way in this setup to prevent this image from auto-resizing with the row?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? Like you, I'd want to keep this non-dev friendly

Comment: @clinch: Ultimately I had to go with the solution below.  If there's another way, I never found it.  I basically created a console app which would take a user-made Excel template (with known contents, there was little the users could edit there) and process it once to produce a version that the main app could then use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem. The solution for me was to use an absolute positioned anchor for the image, which you can't do in Excel itself for some reason ...

I build a console application to generate a template Excel file with the OpenXML SDK using code similar to the code from [here](http://polymathprogrammer.com/2009/11/30/how-to-insert-an-image-in-excel-open-xml/). Code for the anchor:

```
Position pos = new Position();
pos.X = 0;
pos.Y = 0;
Extent ext = new Extent();
ext.Cx = extents.Cx;
ext.Cy = extents.Cy;
AbsoluteAnchor anchor = new AbsoluteAnchor();
anchor.Position = pos;
anchor.Extent = ext;
anchor.Append(picture);
anchor.Append(new ClientData());
```

Full code hidden in a code snippet for emergencies:

```js
static void Main(string[] args)
{
 string sFile = "ExcelOpenXmlWithImage.xlsx";
 if (File.Exists(sFile))
 {
  File.Delete(sFile);
 }
 BuildWorkbook(sFile);
}

private static void BuildWorkbook(string filename)
{
 try
 {
  using (SpreadsheetDocument xl = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filename, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
  {
   WorkbookPart wbp = xl.AddWorkbookPart();
   WorksheetPart wsp = wbp.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
   Workbook wb = new Workbook();
   FileVersion fv = new FileVersion();
   fv.ApplicationName = "Microsoft Office Excel";
   Worksheet ws = new Worksheet();
   SheetData sd = new SheetData();

   string sImagePath = "polymathlogo.png";
   DrawingsPart dp = wsp.AddNewPart<DrawingsPart>();
   ImagePart imgp = dp.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Png, wsp.GetIdOfPart(dp));
   using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(sImagePath, FileMode.Open))
   {
    imgp.FeedData(fs);
   }

   NonVisualDrawingProperties nvdp = new NonVisualDrawingProperties();
   nvdp.Id = 1025;
   nvdp.Name = "Picture 1";
   nvdp.Description = "polymathlogo";
   DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.PictureLocks picLocks = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.PictureLocks();
   picLocks.NoChangeAspect = true;
   picLocks.NoChangeArrowheads = true;
   NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties nvpdp = new NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties();
   nvpdp.PictureLocks = picLocks;
   NonVisualPictureProperties nvpp = new NonVisualPictureProperties();
   nvpp.NonVisualDrawingProperties = nvdp;
   nvpp.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties = nvpdp;

   DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Stretch stretch = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Stretch();
   stretch.FillRectangle = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.FillRectangle();

   BlipFill blipFill = new BlipFill();
   DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Blip blip = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Blip();
   blip.Embed = dp.GetIdOfPart(imgp);
   blip.CompressionState = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.BlipCompressionValues.Print;
   blipFill.Blip = blip;
   blipFill.SourceRectangle = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.SourceRectangle();
   blipFill.Append(stretch);

   DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Transform2D t2d = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Transform2D();
   DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Offset offset = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Offset();
   offset.X = 0;
   offset.Y = 0;
   t2d.Offset = offset;
   Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(sImagePath);
   //http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Metric_Unit#DrawingML
   //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341930/pixel-to-centimeter
   //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139655/how-to-convert-pixels-to-points-px-to-pt-in-net-c
   DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Extents extents = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Extents();
   extents.Cx = (long)bm.Width * (long)((float)914400 / bm.HorizontalResolution);
   extents.Cy = (long)bm.Height * (long)((float)914400 / bm.VerticalResolution);
   bm.Dispose();
   t2d.Extents = extents;
   ShapeProperties sp = new ShapeProperties();
   sp.BlackWhiteMode = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.BlackWhiteModeValues.Auto;
   sp.Transform2D = t2d;
   DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.PresetGeometry prstGeom = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.PresetGeometry();
   prstGeom.Preset = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle;
   prstGeom.AdjustValueList = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.AdjustValueList();
   sp.Append(prstGeom);
   sp.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.NoFill());

   DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.Picture picture = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.Picture();
   picture.NonVisualPictureProperties = nvpp;
   picture.BlipFill = blipFill;
   picture.ShapeProperties = sp;

   Position pos = new Position();
   pos.X = 0;
   pos.Y = 0;
   Extent ext = new Extent();
   ext.Cx = extents.Cx;
   ext.Cy = extents.Cy;
   AbsoluteAnchor anchor = new AbsoluteAnchor();
   anchor.Position = pos;
   anchor.Extent = ext;
   anchor.Append(picture);
   anchor.Append(new ClientData());
   WorksheetDrawing wsd = new WorksheetDrawing();
   wsd.Append(anchor);
   Drawing drawing = new Drawing();
   drawing.Id = dp.GetIdOfPart(imgp);

   wsd.Save(dp);

   ws.Append(sd);
   ws.Append(drawing);
   wsp.Worksheet = ws;
   wsp.Worksheet.Save();
   Sheets sheets = new Sheets();
   Sheet sheet = new Sheet();
   sheet.Name = "Sheet1";
   sheet.SheetId = 1;
   sheet.Id = wbp.GetIdOfPart(wsp);
   sheets.Append(sheet);
   wb.Append(fv);
   wb.Append(sheets);

   xl.WorkbookPart.Workbook = wb;
   xl.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
   xl.Close();
  }
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
  Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
  Console.ReadLine();
 }
}
```

Comment: This looks really useful.  It may be a day or so before I get a chance to really play around with it, but super helpful.  It may not solve my needs for the long run because non-technical personnel may want to modify these Excel templates, but I'll test that and in any event that part is outside the scope of the question.  This is great, thanks!