# how to change size of picture using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

there.
I want to change size of picture using openpyxl.
width = 11.21 cm.
height = 7.69 cm.

or I want to change the size of picture same as the cell.

my code is below. it makes very small size picture.
could you help me?

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image

filename="1.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(filename)
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
img = Image('13.5.jpg')
img.width = 11.21
img.height = 7.69
ws.add_image(img, 'B13')
wb.save('1.xlsx')
print("done")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`openpyxl.drawing.image.Image` is based on `PIL.Image`. In `PIL.Image`, the unit of image size is pixel. So you should first calculate the image's width and height in pixel.

The formula is(Ref: [Pixel to Centimeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341930/pixel-to-centimeter)):

> pixels = cms * dpi / 2.54

You can get dpi of that image by `img.info['dpi']`.

Comment: openpyxl.drawing.image.Image has no attribute `info`.  

Here's the source: https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/blob/branch/3.1/openpyxl/drawing/image.py

Furthermore, it's not clear how a raster pixel array would even need a dots per inch (dpi) value anyway.

Answer (score 8):

For clarification to anyone else (keineahnung2345 has the correct post, mine is just supplementary) this is how to set image size:

```
img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('filelocation.png')
img.height = # insert image height in pixels as float or int (e.g. 305.5)
img.width= # insert image width in pixels as float or int (e.g. 405.8)
img.anchor = 'A1' # where you want image to be anchored/start from
sheet.add_image(img) # adding in the image
```

Again be sure to check dpi which acts as a multiplier on the pixel amount.
You can check image size by clicking on the image in excel and inspecting the properties, which should give you a size in inches or centimeters.

For anyone using inches, here is a inches to pixel converter:
https://www.unitconverters.net/typography/inch-to-pixel-x.htm

The centimeter converter can be found in the selected answer from keineahnung2345.