# Converting between WPF font size and "standard" font size

Tags: .net, wpf, font-size

I've noticed in WPF, the default font size of 12 points is roughly equivalent to 9 points in "normal" applications (e.g. WordPad), 10 pt in WPF is roughly 7 pt standard, and when I try to match the default font size of 10 pt in WordPad in WPF, I've found 13 is the closest.

First of all, why does WPF use such bizarre non-standard font sizes, and secondly, is there a reliable way to convert between the two?

My reason for asking is I want to build a font size menu with "standard" font sizes of 9, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 24, 36, 48, but I'm pretty sure if I use those actual values they will be wildly off.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

WPF uses pixels as its default unit for [font size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.fontsize.aspx). The mapping between [points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)) (probably what you mean when you say "standard" font size) and pixels is: 1 pt = (96/72) px

This gives us a simple conversion function:

```
public static double PointsToPixels(double points)
{
    return points*(96.0/72.0);
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139655/how-to-convert-pixels-to-points-px-to-pt-in-net-c) for more details.

Comment: Thanks! That does appear to be the missing key. I also see I can specify font sizes with a "qualified double" and specify points as the unit, however I wonder how to do that from code.

Comment: Worth pointing out that WPF documentation confuses the matter considerably by referring to these 1/96 inch pixels as "em units" which is completely different to the typographical meaning of "em" (as used with [CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-length))

Comment: I was curious to see if Windows DPI mattered so I dug into the .Net reference source, and it does not. The FontSizeConverter uses the LengthConverter to convert from a string to double, and that has the following array:

        static private double[] PixelUnitFactors = 
        { 
            1.0,              // Pixel itself
            96.0,             // Pixels per Inch
            96.0 / 2.54,      // Pixels per Centimeter
            96.0 / 72.0,      // Pixels per Point
        };

Answer (score 22):

Another method for conversion if you're going from point to WPF double is to use the System.Windows.FontSizeConverter class:

```
double sizeForWpf = (double) new FontSizeConverter().ConvertFrom("10pt");
```