# VBA gives wrong plotarea width?

Tags: vba, excel-2007

I want to get the PlotArea width and height in order to calculate the proportion.
I used `ActiveChart.PlotArea.Width` to get the width, and then tested the width using Photoshop.

I discovered that the width returned by `ActiveChart.PlotArea.Width` is wrong.

Image shows what I am talking about:
[image]

I have no Idea why...

Please help me to understand why it happens and how to fix it...

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PlotArea.Width is returning the width in points not pixels.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff198324.aspx

Points are a unit of length.  Pixels are variable on a number of factors like monitor, fonts, truefont settings, ect.  Here is a SO post about converting pixels to points: [Convert Pixels to Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139655/how-to-convert-pixels-to-points-px-to-pt-in-net-c)