# VB Windows form will not size to applications width/height

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I have a Visual Basic Windows Form size set to be the applications width/height but it's not working.

While this works completely fine for me in VBA, its not working as desired for the AddIn:

```
  Dim newForm As New ExportingForm
  newForm.ShowDialog()

Public Class ExportingForm

  Private Sub ExportingForm_Layout(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Layout

    Dim exclApp As Excel.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application

    If exclApp.WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlMaximized Then
      Me.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized
    Else
      Me.Size = New Drawing.Point(exclApp.Width, exclApp.Height)
    End If
  End Sub

End Class
```

Additionally in Designer mode here are my settings for the Windows Form:

```
IsMdiContainer False
Location       0,0
MaximumSize    0,0
MinimumSize    0,0
Padding        0,0,0,0
Size           250,250
StartPosition  CenterParent
```

It centers fine and I can alter the width/height programmatically just fine as well, however, when setting it to the applications width/height it changes to a certain point and stops. What do I need to do to correct this?

I've also tried :

```
Me.Size = New Drawing.Point(exclApp.ActiveWindow.Width, exclApp.ActiveWindow.Height)
```

And I've also tried setting the size before showing the form:

```
Dim newForm.....
newForm.Size = New Drawing.Point(exclApp.Width, exclApp.Height)
newForm.ShowDialog()
```

I can translate any language you have as long as it works with Visual Studio

[image]

Comment: [Excel.Application.Width](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840678.aspx) and [Excel.Application.Height](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195524.aspx) are measured in points. [Form.Size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25w4thew(v=vs.110).aspx) is measured in pixels. You have to [convert between the two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139655/convert-pixels-to-points).

Comment: Thanks @Comintern I didn't know that, I even looked on MSDN and it didn't mention that - I'll review your link thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Correction**

In theory the method I originally presented should work, however there are issues with the Excel PointsToScreenPixels methods. An internet search on the functions indicates that results are unreliable at best.  Therefore, I am recommend using the Win32 API function GetWindowRect to retrieve the Excel application's position and size.  The API function definitions where obtained from http://www.pinvoke.net/index.aspx.

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        test()
    End Sub

    Sub test()
        Dim meDPI As PointF = GetDPI(Me.Handle)

        Dim app As New Excel.Application
        app.Visible = True

        Dim appHwnd As IntPtr = New IntPtr(app.Hwnd)

        ' setting Excel's size and position -- just for test verification purposes
        SetWindowPos(appHwnd, IntPtr.Zero, 10, 10, 500, 300, SetWindowPosFlags.DoNotActivate)

        Dim rc As RECT
        GetWindowRect(appHwnd, rc)  ' retrieve Excel's size and position into rc

        app.UserControl = True ' return control to the user 
        Console.WriteLine("Excel located at X: {0}, Y: {1}, Width: {2}, Height: {3}", rc.Left, rc.Top, rc.Width, rc.Height)
        Me.Location = rc.Location
        Me.Size = rc.Size
        Me.Activate() ' bring this form to the front
        Me.Opacity = 0.5 ' allow to view thru to Excel
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function GetDPI(hwnd As IntPtr) As PointF
        Dim ret As PointF
        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(hwnd)
            ret.X = g.DpiX
            ret.Y = g.DpiY
        End Using
        Return ret
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function GetWindowRect(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByRef lpRect As RECT) As Boolean
    End Function

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Public Structure RECT
         Private _Left As Integer, _Top As Integer, _Right As Integer, _Bottom As Integer

         Public Sub New(ByVal Rectangle As Rectangle)
              Me.New(Rectangle.Left, Rectangle.Top, Rectangle.Right, Rectangle.Bottom)
         End Sub
         Public Sub New(ByVal Left As Integer, ByVal Top As Integer, ByVal Right As Integer, ByVal Bottom As Integer)
              _Left = Left
              _Top = Top
              _Right = Right
              _Bottom = Bottom
         End Sub

         Public Property X As Integer
              Get
              Return _Left
              End Get
              Set(ByVal value As Integer)
              _Right = _Right - _Left + value
              _Left = value
              End Set
         End Property
         Public Property Y As Integer
              Get
              Return _Top
              End Get
              Set(ByVal value As Integer)
              _Bottom = _Bottom - _Top + value
              _Top = value
              End Set
         End Property
         Public Property Left As Integer
              Get
              Return _Left
              End Get
              Set(ByVal value As Integer)
              _Left = value
              End Set
         End Property
         Public Property Top As Integer
              Get
              Return _Top
              End Get
              Set(ByVal value As Integer)
              _Top = value
              End Set
         End Property
         Public Property Right As Integer
              Get
              Return _Right
              End Get
              Set(ByVal value As Integer)
              _Right = value
              End Set
         End Property
         Public Property Bottom As Integer
              Get
              Return _Bottom
              End Get
              Set(ByVal value As Integer)
              _Bottom = value
              End Set
         End Property
         Public Property Height() As Integer
              Get
              Return _Bottom - _Top
              End Get
              Set(ByVal value As Integer)
              _Bottom = value + _Top
              End Set
         End Property
         Public Property Width() As Integer
              Get
              Return _Right - _Left
              End Get
              Set(ByVal value As Integer)
              _Right = value + _Left
              End Set
         End Property
         Public Property Location() As Point
              Get
              Return New Point(Left, Top)
              End Get
              Set(ByVal value As Point)
              _Right = _Right - _Left + value.X
              _Bottom = _Bottom - _Top + value.Y
              _Left = value.X
              _Top = value.Y
              End Set
         End Property
         Public Property Size() As Size
              Get
              Return New Size(Width, Height)
              End Get
              Set(ByVal value As Size)
              _Right = value.Width + _Left
              _Bottom = value.Height + _Top
              End Set
         End Property

         Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal Rectangle As RECT) As Rectangle
              Return New Rectangle(Rectangle.Left, Rectangle.Top, Rectangle.Width, Rectangle.Height)
         End Operator
         Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal Rectangle As Rectangle) As RECT
              Return New RECT(Rectangle.Left, Rectangle.Top, Rectangle.Right, Rectangle.Bottom)
         End Operator
         Public Shared Operator =(ByVal Rectangle1 As RECT, ByVal Rectangle2 As RECT) As Boolean
              Return Rectangle1.Equals(Rectangle2)
         End Operator
         Public Shared Operator <>(ByVal Rectangle1 As RECT, ByVal Rectangle2 As RECT) As Boolean
              Return Not Rectangle1.Equals(Rectangle2)
         End Operator

         Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
              Return "{Left: " & _Left & "; " & "Top: " & _Top & "; Right: " & _Right & "; Bottom: " & _Bottom & "}"
         End Function

         Public Overloads Function Equals(ByVal Rectangle As RECT) As Boolean
              Return Rectangle.Left = _Left AndAlso Rectangle.Top = _Top AndAlso Rectangle.Right = _Right AndAlso Rectangle.Bottom = _Bottom
         End Function
         Public Overloads Overrides Function Equals(ByVal [Object] As Object) As Boolean
              If TypeOf [Object] Is RECT Then
              Return Equals(DirectCast([Object], RECT))
              ElseIf TypeOf [Object] Is Rectangle Then
              Return Equals(New RECT(DirectCast([Object], Rectangle)))
              End If

              Return False
         End Function
    End Structure

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function SetWindowPos(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As IntPtr, ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer, ByVal cx As Integer, ByVal cy As Integer, ByVal uFlags As SetWindowPosFlags) As Boolean
    End Function
    <Flags> _
    Private Enum SetWindowPosFlags As UInteger
         ''' <summary>If the calling thread and the thread that owns the window are attached to different input queues,
         ''' the system posts the request to the thread that owns the window. This prevents the calling thread from
         ''' blocking its execution while other threads process the request.</summary>
         ''' <remarks>SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS</remarks>
         ASynchronousWindowPosition = &H4000
         ''' <summary>Prevents generation of the WM_SYNCPAINT message.</summary>
         ''' <remarks>SWP_DEFERERASE</remarks>
         DeferErase = &H2000
         ''' <summary>Draws a frame (defined in the window's class description) around the window.</summary>
         ''' <remarks>SWP_DRAWFRAME</remarks>
         DrawFrame = &H20
         ''' <summary>Applies new frame styles set using the SetWindowLong function. Sends a WM_NCCALCSIZE message to
         ''' the window, even if the window's size is not being changed. If this flag is not specified, WM_NCCALCSIZE
         ''' is sent only when the window's size is being changed.</summary>
         ''' <remarks>SWP_FRAMECHANGED</remarks>
         FrameChanged = &H20
         ''' <summary>Hides the window.</summary>
         ''' <remarks>SWP_HIDEWINDOW</remarks>
         HideWindow = &H80
         ''' <summary>Does not activate the window. If this flag is not set, the window is activated and moved to the
         ''' top of either the topmost or non-topmost group (depending on the setting of the hWndInsertAfter
         ''' parameter).</summary>
         ''' <remarks>SWP_NOACTIVATE</remarks>
         DoNotActivate = &H10
         ''' <summary>Discards the entire contents of the client area. If this flag is not specified, the valid
         ''' contents of the client area are saved and copied back into the client area after the window is sized or
         ''' repositioned.</summary>
         ''' <remarks>SWP_NOCOPYBITS</remarks>
         DoNotCopyBits = &H100
         ''' <summary>Retains the current position (ignores X and Y parameters).</summary>
         ''' <remarks>SWP_NOMOVE</remarks>
         IgnoreMove = &H2
         ''' <summary>Does not change the owner window's position in the Z order.</summary>
         ''' <remarks>SWP_NOOWNERZORDER</remarks>
         DoNotChangeOwnerZOrder = &H200
         ''' <summary>Does not redraw changes. If this flag is set, no repainting of any kind occurs. This applies to
         ''' the client area, the nonclient area (including the title bar and scroll bars), and any part of the parent
         ''' window uncovered as a result of the window being moved. When this flag is set, the application must
         ''' explicitly invalidate or redraw any parts of the window and parent window that need redrawing.</summary>
         ''' <remarks>SWP_NOREDRAW</remarks>
         DoNotRedraw = &H8
         ''' <summary>Same as the SWP_NOOWNERZORDER flag.</summary>
         ''' <remarks>SWP_NOREPOSITION</remarks>
         DoNotReposition = &H200
         ''' <summary>Prevents the window from receiving the WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING message.</summary>
         ''' <remarks>SWP_NOSENDCHANGING</remarks>
         DoNotSendChangingEvent = &H400
         ''' <summary>Retains the current size (ignores the cx and cy parameters).</summary>
         ''' <remarks>SWP_NOSIZE</remarks>
         IgnoreResize = &H1
         ''' <summary>Retains the current Z order (ignores the hWndInsertAfter parameter).</summary>
         ''' <remarks>SWP_NOZORDER</remarks>
         IgnoreZOrder = &H4
         ''' <summary>Displays the window.</summary>
         ''' <remarks>SWP_SHOWWINDOW</remarks>
         ShowWindow = &H40
    End Enum

End Class
```

Please note that in testing the above code, the WinForm application is declared to be DPI aware by having the following in its app.Manifest file.

```
  <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
```

---

**Do Not Use**

The [Application.Height Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195524.aspx) and [Application.Width Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840678.aspx) is measured in points not pixels.  You can use the [Window.PointsToScreenPixelsX Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838206.aspx) and the [Window.PointsToScreenPixelsY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840559.aspx) methods to compute the width and height in pixels to set your form size.

`width = exclApp.ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsX(exclApp.Width)`

`height = exclApp.ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsY(exclApp.Height)`

I do not know if you will also have to declare your addin as DPI aware to avoid Windows's scaling your form.

Note: Base on testing in Excel, only the ActiveWindow will yield a value.

Comment: This isn't right per sey, if your validating against `Window(1)` PointsToPixels, you should use it's Points instead of `exclApp.Width`. Otherwise you will get erroneous deminsions. Additionally the periods before the parameter shouldn't be there. Otherwise its the right answer. Thanks

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I edited to prevent confusion for future question seekers. I think DPI awareness might be good for users with dual monitors or greater. I'll have to look into that some more thanks

Comment: @soulshined,  I just did so testing in Excel.  The window needs to be the ActiveWindow or else the function returns zero.  Also, the source of the value converted does not matter as long as it is the proper value. `exclApp.Windows(1).Width` is not the same as `exclApp.Width`.  I'll edit the post.

Comment: Yeah, I personally used `ActiveWindow` but kept your variable for your answer the same so I didn't see any thing out of the norm. I tested it with `exclApp.Width` and it produced a different result for me. I'll keep checking. But after playing around with this some more there are some variables in play. Depending on where the application is in reference to the screen, produces different results. For example, when the application is close to the bottom left the form populates with slightly different dimensions, it might be because I used `exclApp.ActiveWindow.Width`

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't seem like this is a true reliable resource, but it is close enough to get the job done. I don't need to be exact personally, but for those looking for a fine-tuned reliable method, this isn't 100% reliable. When I move the application around the screen and change dimensions before populating the form, it's a different result every time, but still close enough for my needs. I even tested with `(exclApp.Width)` - i'll recheck with DPI awareness

Comment: Oops, well come to find out this isn't optimal at all, but still the right answer lol. This method will even change the forms location if it can't center it to the application (because the ActiveWindow is too low or too high on the screen). I ultimately went with `exclApp.Width * 1.34` | `exclApp.Height * 1.34` to get it close enough, and it still centers. Thanks for you help though. I really appreciate it

Comment: @soulshined, You are correct.  The PointsToScreenPixels methods appear to have a long history of causing grief.  I have posted a retraction of the original answer and presented an alternative.

Comment: It's a shame this is what you have to come to, to accomplish such a trivial task. I used Win32 API's frequently in VBA but for this one time event, I didn't want to incorporate it for my project. I already upvoted you so I can't do anymore, but I really appreciate you taking time to go back and provide such a thorough answer for future question seekers. How do you think we could change the OP title to match your answer for maximum traffic regarding this, since it's not really specific to windows forms?

Comment: @soulshined, I don't do this for forum points.  I do it to learn stuff and I learned something from this.  It was not really that much work.  It just irks me that MS rarely fixes these types of issues as I found gripes about this going back to 2002.  It took them forever to get the Excel UsedRange property to the point that it could be reliably used.  As far as modifying the title, I wouldn't bother as you could probably find many posts on obtaining a window's position and size and that is ultimately what this was about.  It was just easier because Excel exposes its handle. :)